# When saving a webpage from Chrome on Android, where in the file manager can I locate the stored file?

Tags: google

I need to know where are the saved webpages of Google Chrome stored in Android.  I mean, I can access them from the browser itself but I need to know where its stored in the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

The save folder may vary depending on the firmware of your device, but usually it is **mnt / sdcard / download**

Comment: I checked its not there,could you suggest some other place where it will be

Comment: check these paths /data/data/com.android.browser/files/  OR /Download/ OR look for your setings.